# Load external properties file with same keys

Tags: java, spring, properties

I have two properties file in a folder in file system.
The path of this folder is passed using system properties -D=path/to/properties/folder

ex: java -jar -DpropDir=abc/def app.jar

These are properties files.
Please note that both files have common key username,password.

mysql.properties

```
url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306
username=root
password=pass
```

vertica.properties

```
dburl=jdbc:vertica://123.123.123:4321/abcd
username=abcd
password=pass123
```

Now I want to access all these properties in respective classes.
MySqlProperties.java and VerticaProperties.java like this.

```
@Component
public class VerticaProperties {

    @Value("${dburl}")
    private String dburl;
    @Value("${username}")
    private String username;
    @Value("${password}")
    private String password;

    public String getDbUrl() {
        return dburl;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
}
```

and similarly MySqlProperties.java

```
@Component
public class MySqlProperties {

    @Value("${url}")
    private String url;
    @Value("${username}")
    private String username;
    @Value("${password}")
    private String password;

    public String getDbUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
}
```

But as key is same value is overriding for username and password.

How to access mysql.properties in MySqlProperties.java and vertica.properties in VerticaProperties.java classes.

Comment: How you add those properties to context? Using `PropertySource`?

Comment: @talex I am using PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer bean.

Comment: Only way I see is create your own `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` which will add prefix to keys, but it will be easier to just add prefix manually to your properties.

Comment: @talex I tried the prefix method but its not working.
config.setPlaceholderPrefix("${mysql.");   Getting this error "Could not resolve placeholder 'vertica.dburl' in value "${vertica.dburl}""

Answer (score 1):

You import external properties using @PropertySource

Given the location is shared as

-Dmysql.properties=file:/path-to-mysql.properties -Dvertica.properties=file:/path-to-vertica.properties

```
@Component
@PropertySource("${vertica.properties}")
public class VerticaProperties {
.....
}

@Component
@PropertySource("${mysql.properties}")
public class MySqlProperties {
....
}
```

or  Given
 -Dmysql.properties=/path-to-mysql.properties -Dvertica.properties=/path-to-vertica.properties

```
@Component
    @PropertySource("file:${vertica.properties}")
    public class VerticaProperties {
    .....
    }

    @Component
    @PropertySource("file:${mysql.properties}")
    public class MySqlProperties {
    ....
    }
```

Additionally , you may also use prefix with **@ConfigurationProperties** along with @PropertySource.

The annotation works best when we have hierarchical properties that all have the same prefix, so we mention the prefix too as a part of the annotation.

Add prefix to keys  like  mysql.url ,  vertica.url in respective files

```
@Component
@PropertySource("${vertica.properties}")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="vertica")
public class VerticaProperties {
.....
}

@Component
@PropertySource("${mysql.properties}")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="mysql")
public class MySqlProperties {
....
}
```

Comment: Or use `@PropertySource("${propDir}/mysql.properties")` and have only one `-D` as in question.

Comment: When we use PropertySource the key value pairs can be accessed using Environment.getProperty method. But as both files have same key username, password its overriding the previous value. @talex